# Chrome downloads display white font on white background

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using the "Just black" theme for chrome, but "downloads" are showing as white text on a white background.

How do I fix this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnbSu.png)
[image]

Comment: If you try a different theme, or disable your themes entirely, is the issue fixed?

Comment: @music2myear I tried different themes and half of it had the same incident

Comment: Have you tried no theme?

Comment: @music2myear With default theme it displays normally

Comment: Then it should be rather obvious that the problem is with the themes, or with Chrome's support of the themes right now. The fix is to not use themes until the problem is fixed by Google and/or the theme authors.